# How to profile a golang test suite that uses the gocheck test framework

Tags: go, profiling

I'm attempting to profile a golang test suite that uses the [gocheck](https://labix.org/gocheck) test framework.

I'm running the following commands to start the test with profiling:

```
go test -c -o integration.test -cpuprofile cpu.prof -blockprofile block.prof
./integration.test -test.cpuprofile cpu.prof -test.blockprofile block.prof
```

The test suite runs as it would normally, and produces the two expected files. The total test execution time is approxiately 50 minutes. The problem is with the contents of the files.

If I create a report with `go tool pprof` or [go-torch](https://github.com/uber/go-torch) the profiles appear to only contain data for a few seconds, instead of the entire test run (50 minutes).

If I look at the stdout of the test runs, I notice some tests are much slower than others, and run for 50s, but those slow tests don't even appear in the profile data.

I believe something is causing pprof to write out incorrect data, but I'm not sure what that might be. My only guess is that it has to do with `gocheck`s use of `panic()` to run every test and test fixture.

This [profile1.zip](https://github.com/docker/docker/files/450711/profile1.zip) contains: the test binary, the profiles, and a framegraph report from them.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the integration tests are calling `exec.Command` to exec the docker binary directly (these are integration tests after all). You can't profile what's going on in the child processes, and the tests likely spend most of the time just waiting for these external processes.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is expected. That is why I have enabled the blocking profiler. Shouldn't it be capturing all the blocking events? Also, even if we were to say that 90% of the time was spent waiting on blocking calls, I would still expect a profile with the other 10% of the time, but the cpu profile only has a total of 140 samples! That's not even 0.05% of the time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about the rest of the possibly missing data, just that there's not going to be a whole lot of useful samples from this type of test.

Comment: I think it could still be useful. The flamegraphs should still show slower areas.  Do you have a suggestions for an alternative way to profile this type of code?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years, but along the way I have figured this out.

The step I was missing was to first use `go test -trace trace.out`. The execution trace works more like the instrumented profilers I was used to in other languages. To get more fine granted data I can also use https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/trace to add regions and tasks.

From the trace I should be able to see where goroutines spent the most time (cpu, sync blocking, or io). The breakdown of those times in the regions is particularly interesting.

Once I have that data, I can look at the appropriate profile. For example if most of the time is spent in io, I would look at the IO profile.